# How to align 3 html tables to center, side by side

Tags: html, css, html-table, center

I have the below code in html, which I need to center them in the page.

I tried aligning each table to center, it didn't work. I am using div tag which is aligned to center still the tables are not getting centered. Any help please

```
<div align="center">
<table border='1' style="border-color: white;float:left; width:25%">
<tr>
    <th colspan="2">Row 1</td>        
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 2</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 3</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 4</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 5</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 6</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 7</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 8</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 9</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 10</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table border='1' style="border-color: white;float:left; width:25%">
<tr>
    <th colspan="2">Row 1</td>        
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 2</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 3</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 4</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 5</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 6</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 7</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 8</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 9</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 10</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table border='1' style="border-color: white;float:left; width:25%">
<tr>
    <th colspan="2">Row 1</td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 2</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 3</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 4</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 5</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 6</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 7</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 8</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 9</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 10</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: what kind of center, center mean `grid`?

Comment: means filling the page such a way where, first 12.5% of the page blank, next 25% for table1, next 25% for table 2, next for table 3 and rest 12.5% blank again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `flex` box approach like :

```css
.center{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
<table border='1' class="table" style="border-color: white;float:left; width:25%">
<tr>
    <th colspan="2">Row 1</td>        
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 2</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 3</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 4</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 5</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 6</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 7</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 8</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 9</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 10</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table id="mainTable2" border='1' class="table" style="border-color: white;float:left; width:25%">
<tr>
    <th colspan="2">Row 1</td>        
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 2</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 3</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 4</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 5</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 6</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 7</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 8</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 9</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 10</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table id="mainTable3" border='1' class="table" style="border-color: white;float:left; width:25%">
<tr>
    <th colspan="2">Row 1</td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 2</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 3</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 4</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 5</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 6</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 7</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 8</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 9</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 10</td>
    <td>Dummy Data</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```